# Resetting the state of provider

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I am using Riverpod to manage the state of my FLutter app.

Here you have the two providers I am using:

```
final numFotosMensajeProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref){
  return 0;
});
final numVideosMensajeProvider = StateProvider<int>((ref){
  return 0;
});
```

I am incrementing the state using:

```
void incrementNumFotos(BuildContext){
    context.read(numFotosMensajeProvider).state++;
  }
  void incrementNumVideos(BuildContext){
    context.read(numVideosMensajeProvider).state++;
  }
```

like:

```
incrementNumFotos(context);
incrementNumVideos(context);
```

Each time I call `incrementNumFotos(context)` or `incrementNumVideos(context)` the state is changing correctly.

But now I need to reset the state to 0.

What kind of function should I use to reset to 0 the state of the provider?

Comment: which package are you using? provider, riverpod or state_notifier?

Comment: @TirthPatel, as said in my question I am using Riverpod

Comment: I missed it. Cool, you could do `context.read(numVideosMensajeProvider).state = 0`. Not sure if that's right way to do it.

Comment: @TirthPatel, let me try

Comment: @mvasco Can you please share the updated code where you try to set the state to 0?

Comment: @TirthPatel, it works, thank you.

Comment: @AlexHartford, it is working as I said

Comment: @TirthPatel, would you mind creating an answer with your proposal, I would like to accept it as answer to my question.

Comment: @mvasco I'm glad I could help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do `context.read(numVideosMensajeProvider).state = 0;` to reset the value to 0.